# How can I send a file in Node js using Express and Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, multer

I am trying to send a file to my node js server from the front end
here is my codes
HTML

```
<form
  id="file-upload-form"
  class="uploader"
  action="/upload"
  method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
  <input
    id="file-upload"
    type="file"
    name="fileUpload"
    accept=".txt, .doc, .docx, .odt, .xls, .xlsx, .ods, .ppt, .pptx, .odp, .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif"
  />

  <label for="file-upload" id="file-drag">
    <img id="file-image" src="#" alt="Preview" class="hidden" />
    <img
      id="document-icon"
      src="#"
      alt="Document Icon"
      class="hidden"
    />
    <div id="start">
      <img src="assets/download.png" alt="upload" />
      <div>
        <span class="selectText">Select a file or drag here</span>
      </div>
      <div id="notimage" class="hidden">Please select an image</div>
      <span id="file-upload-btn" class="btn btn-primary"
        >Select a file</span
      >
    </div>
    <div id="response" class="hidden">
      <div id="messages"></div>
      <progress class="progress" id="file-progress" value="0">
        <span>0</span>%
      </progress>
    </div>
  </label>
</form>
```

and this is the JavaScript code In the front end (just part of it, because it is used to validate the document)

```
function uploadFile(file) {
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  fileInput = document.getElementById("class-roster-file"),
  pBar = document.getElementById("file-progress"),
  fileSizeLimit = 15; // In MB

  if (xhr.upload) {
  // Check if file is less than x MB
  if (file.size <= fileSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024) {
    // Progress bar
    pBar.style.display = "inline";
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("loadstart", setProgressMaxValue, false);
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateFileProgress, false);

    // File received / failed
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        // Everything is good!
        document.getElementById("file-progress").className =
          xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure";
        // document.location.reload(true);
      }
    };

    // Start upload
    xhr.open(
      "POST",
      document.getElementById("file-upload-form").action,
      true
    );
    xhr.send(file);
  } else {
    output("Please upload a smaller file (< " + fileSizeLimit + " MB).");
  }
}
}
```

and my back end logics are here

```
// Set up Multer for handling file uploads
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "submited_documents/");
   },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
 const fileName = file.originalname.split(".");
 cb(
  null,
  `${fileName[0]}-${Math.floor(100 + Math.random() * 900)}${generateRandomString(3)}.${fileName[1]}`
 );
 },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

 // Endpoint for handling file uploads
  app.post("/upload", upload.single("fileUpload"), (req, res) => {
 const uploadedFile = req.file;

  res.json(req.file);
});
```

Now my problem is, the file is not received in the back end, I mean it come as undefined,
I tried and I think its something to do with content-type, because if I use post-man to send a post request with the file, it works just fine, but its not doing the same with front end I built!!!

I tried multiple ways, using POSTMAN to send the request, the content-type is set automatically and it works as intended but thats different case in the frontend code

Comment: in the xhr request, inside the `xhr.send(file);` function - dont send the file as is. you need to pass it as formData ```const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileUpload', file);``` ```xhr.send(formData);```

Answer (score 0):

To upload the file to the server, you would need to use `FormData`. Firstly, you need to create FormData object and then send this object to the server.

E.g.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("filename", file);
xhr.send(formData);
```